# PDF specification compliance testing sample files

Tags: pdf

I have an application that converts images, and would like to test it against some of the various PDF specs.  Does anyone know of a location with some sample PDF documents that implement different spec levels that I can use to test?  I would like to convert to a different format (e.g. tiff) and test for an accurate representation of the viewable PDF.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I found these resources:

1. [Stillhq.com PDF Database/Mikail's PDF database](http://www.stillhq.com/pdfdb/db.html) A large number of real world PDFs, some of which are broken. Free. [(archived here](https://github.com/pdf-raku/stillhq.com-pdfdb))
2. [QualityLogic’s PDF 1.7 Application Test Suite (ATS)](http://www.qualitylogic.com/Contents/Printer-MFP/Technology/PDF.aspx). Commercial.
3. [Adobe PDF test suites](https://web.archive.org/web/20150228065245/http://acroeng.adobe.com/wp/?page_id=10) (Web Archive link, no PDFs available).
4. [Ghent Working Group Test Suites](http://www.gwg.org/download/test-suites/ghent-output-suite/) A number of easy to judge patches that show support (or lack thereof) of essential PDF features. Oriented towards graphic arts and support for PDF features that are part of PDF/X-1a and PDF/X-4. Free to use for workflow / RIP / hardware validation.
5. [PDF cabinet of horrors](http://www.opf-labs.org/format-corpus/pdfCabinetOfHorrors/). Free archive of bad pdf files

Also of interest:

1. [Altona Test Suite](http://www.altonatestsuite.com/en/index.php) Commercial test suite aimed at printing houses
2. [Isartor Test Suite](//www.pdfa.org/isartor-test-suite/) Free test suite for PDF/A-1 compliance
3. [Bavaria Test suitde](http://www.pdflib.com/knowledge-base/pdfa/validation-report/) Free test suite for PDF/A-1 compliance

Comment: @BorislavIvanov: Thx. Why didn't you go through suggested edits?

Answer (score -1):

https://github.com/pdf-association/pdf-corpora lists a variety of PDF test suites.